# I want to run a python script periodically with a variable persisted each repetition. How can I do this?

Tags: python

I have a python script which moves a robot based on a bearing. The bearing calculated is relative to another robot. I want to calculate a corrective factor based on the magnetic bearing the robot is moving along + the change in distance from other points in the network. this corrective factor could then be applied to the bearing calculated relative to another bot to make the bearing closer to a true magnetic bearing ( I have worked out the maths behind this but don't think there is a need to go into the details here).

the way my script runs is by calling other scripts and passing values to and reading them from them. A light piece of pseduo code looks like:

```
find a bearing relative to another bot to the point to be reached
move towards it along this bearing
test accuracy of the bearing
calculate a correction factor
```

I then want to repeat the script and correct the bearing initially calculated with the correction factor (simple add or subtract x degrees)

How can I persist the variable each time the script repeats so that the correction factor can be added or subtracted from the next time instead of having to be recalculated from scratch?

Comment: Store the variable's value in a file, read that file in next time around.

Comment: pickle it / json it/ shelve it / store it in some sql ... etc

Comment: Write it to a file a retrieve it. Use serialization like pickle/json before storing and after retrieving to retain the object hierarchy.

Comment: Why this approach and not just a simple loop inside Python?

Comment: I have no reason for or against either idea - I just want the most robust solution.

Comment: The question concerning persistence of data is irrelevant when you only run a program once and have the loop inside. The exception is if you need to persist the data even then between different runs.

Comment: Yeh, for what I want to do I could loop the process inside the script instead of running it at intervals from the cli.

Answer (score 2):

Store it in a file like that:

```
import json
json.dump(data, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

and red it next time with

```
f = open(filename)
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: I don't understand the 1st part. Why the last line `data = json.load(open(filename))`? What does it do?

Comment: `json.load(open(filename))` opens a file and passes it to the function to load JSON from it. This is basic Python syntax, so I'm a bit puzzled what your question is. That said, you should open a file in a with-clause for proper cleanup and exception safety.

Comment: just edited, you didn't need that it was to read the data back

Answer (score 0):

Json is human-readable and nice. Another good way to serialize data in Python is the [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module. The advantage is that you can store [almost any Python value](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) transparently.

Here's an example:

```
import pickle

def put_persistent(data):
    with open('data.pkl', 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(data, output)

def get_persistent(default=None):
    try:
        with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as pkl_file:
            return pickle.load(pkl_file)
    except IOError:
        return default
```